# Django form not using function parameters correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Im redirect to a page with a form on where the user can upload an image and comment but I keep getting errors.

I'm trying to make it so that the forbrief field automatically gets via the pk when this function was called.

**models.py**

```
class Designs(models.Model):
    forbrief = models.ForeignKey(Brief, on_delete=CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postedby = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    design = models.ImageField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Designs
        fields = ['description', "design",]
```

**Views.py**

```
def designUpload(request, pk):

    render(request, "users/upload_design_page.html")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.forbrief = pk
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'users/upload_design_page.html')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'users/upload_design_page.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

**Errors**

```
Cannot assign "1": "Designs.forbrief" must be a "Brief" instance.
```

Comment: What errors? Add complete error traceback

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i have updated with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close, but you should use `.forbrief_id` instead of `.forbrief` and furthermore set the `.postedby` to `request.user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def designUpload(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.forbrief_id = pk
            form.postedby = request.user
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'users/upload_design_page.html')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'users/upload_design_page.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I had been stuck on that for a while!!